# Zurich Lake boat ride

Tags: zurich, lakes

There is a [boat ride at the Zurich lake](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g188113-d285099-Reviews-Lake_Zurich-Zurich.html) and I want to know where can I get the boat for that boat ride.

Is there a specific location where I can board that boat?

I guess there are boats that are meant to take you from one part to another of the lake (specific for transportation), but is there a specific boat for tourists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see from the link, you can probably book and load from everywhere.

[Any harbor on the lake of Zurich](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/AttractionProductDetail-g188113-d285099-a_aidSuffix.tvrm-a_partner.Viator-a_product.35163P1-Lake_Zurich-Zurich.html)

This other boat tour says it departs from Zürich Bürkliplatz

[Zurich Lake boat ride](https://www.zsg.ch/en/underway/landing-stage-info/zuerich-buerkliplatz)

Comment: The second link (www.zsg.ch) is what I was looking for.

Comment: @vianna77 Note that although it's a tourist tour, it is still charged as a normal "Zurich public transport" plus a 5CHF surcharge.  As such, you should almost *certainly* buy the day ticket, so you can travel round Zürich as well.

Comment: @MartinBonner , I will be using my Swiss Travel Pass ;) Thanks for the reminder though!